# Carregar itens em uma combobox a partir do select de outra combobox

Tags: delphi-xe6, c++-builder

Tenho uma Combobox que lista unidades escolares vindas do meu BD. Segue o código:

```
_fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)   {
QueryUnidade->Close();
QueryUnidade->Open();

while (QueryUnidade->Eof == false){
   ComboBoxUn->Items->Add(QueryUnidade->FieldByName("unidade")->AsString);
   QueryUnidade->Next();
}

}
```

Na minha outra combobox preciso listar os Turnos que estão associados a unidade escolhida na primeira combobox, mas não está aparecendo. Meu código está assim:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ComboBoxTurnoChange(TObject *Sender)    {

QueryTurno->Close();
QueryTurno->ClearFields();
QueryTurno->SQL->Add("SELECT DISTINCT TURNO FROM ALUNO WHERE UNIDADE ='"+  (Trim(ComboBoxUn->Text)+"'"));
QueryTurno->Open();

while(QueryTurno->Eof == false){
    ComboBoxTurno->Items->Add(QueryTurno->FieldByName("turno")->AsString);
   QueryTurno->Next();
}
 ComboBoxTurno->Update();
}
```

Comment: Acrescentando:

É mais legível usar laços usando assim: while not(QueryTurno->Eof) usando a negação not. Apenas sugestão ou dica.

Answer (score 1):

O programa não funcionava porque o certo era fazer o procedimento mostrado no OnSelect da primeira combobox (ComboboxUn). O Código ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ComboBoxUnSelect(TObject *Sender)
{
    QueryTurno->Close();
    QueryTurno->SQL->Add("SELECT DISTINCT TURNO FROM ALUNO WHERE UNIDADE="+QuotedStr(Trim(ComboBoxUn->Text)));
    QueryTurno->Open();

    while(QueryTurno->Eof == false){
       ComboBoxTurno->Items->Add(QueryTurno->FieldByName("turno")->AsString);
       QueryTurno->Next();
    }
}
```

Desta forma quando uma opção for selecionada na primeira combobox automaticamente as outras opções são listadas na segunda.